# Sorting numeric columns in adf data table

Tags: angular, sorting, datatable

I have following method which sorts only string columns and not the numeric columns.

```
setSorting(sorting: DataSorting): void {
        this._sorting = sorting;

        if (sorting && sorting.key) {
            this._rows.sort((a: DataRow, b: DataRow) => {
                let left = a.getValue(sorting.key);
                if (left) {
                    left = (left instanceof Date) ? left.valueOf().toString() : left.toString();
                } else {
                    left = '';
                }

                let right = b.getValue(sorting.key);
                if (right) {
                    right = (right instanceof Date) ? right.valueOf().toString() : right.toString();
                } else {
                    right = '';
                }

                return sorting.direction === 'asc'
                    ? left.localeCompare(right)
                    : right.localeCompare(left);
            });
        }
    }
```

But I want to sort numeric columns also. How to achieve this?
Can anyone please provide solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try two solution :

```
   if (left) {
    if(left instanceof Number){
        left=left.toString();
    }else{
       left = (left instanceof Date) ? left.valueOf().toString() : left.toString();
                    } else {
                        left = '';
                    }
}
```

and the same with rigth:

```
 if (right) {
 if(right instanceof Number){
        right=right.toString();
    }else{
                    right = (right instanceof Date) ? right.valueOf().toString() : right.toString();
                } else {
                    right = '';
                }
}
```

I think must work

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this but if(right instanceof Number){} did not work for me. So I tried isNan(right) to check if it is number. isNan worked for me to check if it is number. Inside that I applied as you suggested  right=right.toString(); But it did not work for me. Still it is sorting as string  only. It is not sorting as numbers.

Comment: How to sort it numerically?

Comment: now i can'try the code but yes you need a method to check is left and right is a number